How to have PHPUnit (11) Output Test Results While They Are Running
I'm currently using PHPUnit 11.4.3.  In previous versions (9? 8?), it used to output the result of a test as it was run.  Now, as it is running, I just get something like:
Runtime:       PHP 8.2.12
Configuration: tests\phpunit.xml

.................................................

Then after it completes, it shows all the test results.
Is there a way to have PHPUnit (v11) output the test results as it runs?
I execute the test from the command line:
vendor\bin\phpunit -c tests\phpunit.xml
PHPUnit 11.4.3 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Runtime:       PHP 8.2.12
Configuration: tests\phpunit.xml

Here is my config file:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<phpunit
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="https://schema.phpunit.de/10.2/phpunit.xsd"
    backupGlobals="true"
    backupStaticProperties="false"
    cacheDirectory=".phpunit.cache"
    cacheResult="false"
    colors="true"
    displayDetailsOnTestsThatTriggerWarnings="true"
    processIsolation="false"
    requireCoverageMetadata="false"
    stopOnError="false"
    stopOnFailure="false"
    stopOnIncomplete="false"
    stopOnSkipped="false"
    stopOnRisky="false"
    testdox="true"
    timeoutForSmallTests="1"
    timeoutForMediumTests="10"
    timeoutForLargeTests="60"
    >
    <coverage/>
    <php>
        <ini
            name="display_errors"
            value="true"/>
    </php>
    <source/>
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="all">
            <file>PageTests.php</file>
            <file>UnitTests.php</file>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>


There was a breaking change and now TestDox mode is no longer used during report execution, it's only used for final report. This change is intentional and is not going to be reverted:

Issue #5883 - Testdox no longer outputs in real-time

This works as intended.
The purpose of the TestDox output is documentation, not "real-time output" and/or being a replacement for the regular output



Your only option at this moment is to write or find a PHPUnit extension that does this. I'm personally using ScriptFUSION/Pip.
